# When I use background-image why does my CSS not apply to the image?

Tags: html, css

When I use `background-image` why does my CSS not apply to the image? If you look at example 1 I'm using `content` which displays my image of myself with all the CSS. However, I need to use `background-image` to ensure the browsers: chrome, safari and firefox can view my image. If you run the snippets in example 2 the CSS isn't applied to the image.

**Question**

is it possible you can get my image to look like example 1 but using `background-image` with all the CSS applied like in example 1?

**EXAMPLE 1**

```css
    .shape {
          border-radius: 25px;
          background: #4D5061;
          content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
          color: white;
          height: 300px;
          margin: auto;
          padding: 3px;
          width: 300px;
          top: 15%;
          left: 50%;
          position: absolute;
          margin-left: -150px;
          z-index: 10;
          }
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

```css
    .shape {
          border-radius: 25px;
          background: #4D5061;
          background-image: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
          color: white;
          height: 300px;
          margin: auto;
          padding: 3px;
          width: 300px;
          top: 15%;
          left: 50%;
          position: absolute;
          margin-left: -150px;
          z-index: 10;
          }
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `background-size:contain;` to scale the background image to cover its container:

```css
    .shape {
          border-radius: 25px;
          background: #4D5061;
          background-image: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
          background-size: contain;
          color: white;
          height: 300px;
          margin: auto;
          padding: 3px;
          width: 300px;
          top: 15%;
          left: 50%;
          position: absolute;
          margin-left: -150px;
          z-index: 10;
       }
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

For this image you can use both 
background-image : 'cover' or 'contain'
It will limit the image within the container.

Here is their difference.
http://cdn.onextrapixel.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/cover-contain.jpg